# Laravel Nova - Include additional css files

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

In Laravel Nova, how to include additional css files?

I have tried following, but gives an error.

```
class NovaServiceProvider extends NovaApplicationServiceProvider
{
    /**
    * Bootstrap any application services.
    *
    * @return void
    */
    public function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        Nova::style('admin', asset('css/admin.css'));
    }
    ...
}
```

Under `public/css` folder I have `admin.css` file.

Error:

> file_get_contents(http://localhost:8099/css/admin.css): failed to open
>   stream: Cannot assign requested address
>   {"exception":"[object]
>   (ErrorException(code: 0):
>   file_get_contents(http://localhost:8099/css/admin.css): failed to open
>   stream: Cannot assign requested address at
>   /var/www/nova/src/Http/Controllers/StyleController.php:20)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`Nova::style` is used to add styles to the existing bundles. Therefor, Laravel Nova needs a direct path to the CSS file so these can be parsed. Use the function [`public_path`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/helpers#method-public-path) to get an absolute path to files in the public folder. This way, Nova can read the files.

```
Nova::style('admin', public_path('css/admin.css'));
```

Comment: Nova::style('admin', asset('css/admin.css')); use asset instead of public_path ( V3 )

Comment: To add to that, one can use it together with Vite: `Nova::style('custom-nova', Vite::asset('resources/scss/nova/nova.scss'));`